# Finding other riders for a cross country tour for charity

Tags: touring

I'm in the early stages of planning a long distance bike tour, and I am looking for people to ride with across/around the country during the summer months.

If you have suggestions on how to find people to ride with, I would appreciate it. Thank you for the read.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not suited to this type of request

Comment: Local knowledge doesn't work well in this forum.  Your best bet is to make contact with locals via cycling clubs or bike shops, or perhaps through work or social group.

Comment: The question is about how to find people, and not actually an attempt to find people in itself. So @Criggie's comment answers the question as written as well as anyone could. I'd add that you'll need to train as well, so finding a local group will help with that too

Comment: Contact one of the bicycle advocacy groups like Cycle America or Adventure Cycling.  They run guided tours, plus (last I was aware) they have a sort of classified ad setup for finding tour companions.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more generic and to fit @Nate’s great answer and @Criggie’s helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the ride will take place from May to September or happen sometime in between those months?

A good place to start would be at your local bike shops, hang out, get to know people in the scene so to speak. Join some local weekly group rides which are done by most bike shops and make some friends. You may also ask the local shops if they have somewhere they would let you hang a flyer or set a stack of them by the register. A couple shops by me have a cork board they will let you hang business cards or flyers on for example.

The issue here is a ride of that magnitude is not just a weekend kind of thing, people will need to make plans ahead of time, take off work, pontentially buy touring gear or any number of other things. Cross country trips take careful planning and execution.

In my opinion one of the best routes will to be to ride with as many people ahead of time so you can to ask around for people that would be interested and get to know the locals that are into this sort of thing. You could also join your local cycling groups on Facebook and start spreading the word and gauging interest through them. One more option would be to take out a classified through either an advocacy group, online, or in a local newspaper if you want to go really old school. With today's technology Facebook may be one of the easier ways to begin. Meet some people interested and take a couple group rides with them before hand to see if you mesh.

Comment: I'd like to start May 1st, and I'd like to finish. Ideally by September 1, 2018. Thank you for the information, this is great.

Answer (score 1):

crazyguyonabike.com is a set of forums and blogs for long distance trekking by bicycle. I have seen such requests there before.

The [Regional: North America](https://www.crazyguyonabike.com/forum/board/?o=1mr&board_id=382&v=e) forum is a common place for people looking for riding partners, discussing routes, etc., across North America.